# How do I prevent junk customer registrations on my store?

Tags: customer, magento-1, captcha

I'm going through my registered customer accounts and see tons of spammy registrations like this:
[image: spam customers]

Is there something I should do to

- delete the existing spam accounts
- prevent future registrations like this.

Also, just out of curiosity, for what reason would these register, who is benefitting from it?

Comment: Did my answer help you? If so, would you mind clicking the checkmark next to it to mark it as accepted? This will help validate the answer for other users and gives me a few points.

Comment: https://magecomp.com/magento-new-recaptcha.html

Answer (score 3):

One solution to this problem would be to add a Recaptcha to your registration, and ensuring that it is validated before the account is created. See this link (https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/index.html) about setting up Recaptcha.

As to why spammers are doing this specifically, I'm afraid that no one can tell you that definitively. However, here are a number of potential reasons:

- Spambots looking to leave links to another page, like you frequently see in blog comments.
- Bots looking for security vulnerabilities in your site.

For what it's worth, the domain fghmail.net is associated with spam (https://stopforumspam.com/ipcheck/91.200.12.143).

Deleting these phony accounts is a fine thing to do, if you're sure that they are phony accounts. Writing a custom data script to delete the customer accounts based on the email address domain name isn't a bad idea, if you're sure that you have no legitimate accounts in your store associated with that domain.

Answer (score 1):

The bots (mostly Russian but used by Chinese as well) are inserting emails from their spam mailing list and in the NAME field they are inserting their spam messages with links.

So they are using your website's mail server to send out their spam messages.

Using proxy servers and multi threaded bots they are capable of registering 2000 new fake customer accounts during 10 minutes.

Captcha will not help as they are bypassing it with direct POST request to your website.

Comment: Wouldn't it be nice to be able to use some of their methods for things like load-testing? :)

Answer (score 1):

We analyzed the traffic and added a simple check in our WAF (which is originally for WordPress)

```
// Extra Magento POST variables
if ( false !== strpos( $request_path, '/customer/account/createpost' )
    && ( isset( $_POST['birthyear'] ) ||  isset( $_POST['sYear'] ) || isset( $_POST['year'] ) )
) {
    return 'bad_request_post_magento_vars';
}
```

So if unnecessary variables are present the firewall will block the offender ASAP.

[WAF for WordPress](https://github.com/szepeviktor/wordpress-fail2ban)

Comment: PLEASE get into the habit of using Magento wrappers.  `Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost()`...

Comment: I am sorry. I haven't mentioned that our WAF runs from the `auto_prepend_file` directive, so Magento is not yet started.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification... I apologize for comment in this instance then, but would like to re-direct to anyone who is within the Magento framework.

Answer (score 0):

You can use default Magento Captcha for registration. Check it under `Stores - Configuration - Customers - Customer Configuration - CAPTCHA` and set these settings:

[image]

Comment: This is for magento 2

Answer (score 0):

Please add google invisible captcha and do server-side validation.

```
<?php class Addpeople_Validatecaptcha_Model_Customer_Customer extends Mage_Customer_Model_Customer {
/**
 * Validate customer attribute values.
 * For existing customer password + confirmation will be validated only when password is set (i.e. its change is requested)
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function validate()
{
    $errors = array();
    if (!Zend_Validate::is( trim($this->getFirstname()) , 'NotEmpty')) {
        $errors[] = Mage::helper('customer')->__('The first name cannot be empty.');
    }

    if (!Zend_Validate::is( trim($this->getLastname()) , 'NotEmpty')) {
        $errors[] = Mage::helper('customer')->__('The last name cannot be empty.');
    }

    if (!Zend_Validate::is($this->getEmail(), 'EmailAddress')) {
        $errors[] = Mage::helper('customer')->__('Invalid email address "%s".', $this->getEmail());
    }

    $password = $this->getPassword();
    if (!$this->getId() && !Zend_Validate::is($password , 'NotEmpty')) {
        $errors[] = Mage::helper('customer')->__('The password cannot be empty.');
    }
    if (strlen($password) && !Zend_Validate::is($password, 'StringLength', array(self::MINIMUM_PASSWORD_LENGTH))) {
        $errors[] = Mage::helper('customer')
            ->__('The minimum password length is %s', self::MINIMUM_PASSWORD_LENGTH);
    }
    if (strlen($password) && !Zend_Validate::is($password, 'StringLength', array('max' => self::MAXIMUM_PASSWORD_LENGTH))) {
        $errors[] = Mage::helper('customer')
            ->__('Please enter a password with at most %s characters.', self::MAXIMUM_PASSWORD_LENGTH);
    }
    $confirmation = $this->getPasswordConfirmation();
    if ($password != $confirmation) {
        $errors[] = Mage::helper('customer')->__('Please make sure your passwords match.');
    }

    $entityType = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getEntityType('customer');
    $attribute = Mage::getModel('customer/attribute')->loadByCode($entityType, 'dob');
    if ($attribute->getIsRequired() && '' == trim($this->getDob())) {
        $errors[] = Mage::helper('customer')->__('The Date of Birth is required.');
    }
    $attribute = Mage::getModel('customer/attribute')->loadByCode($entityType, 'taxvat');
    if ($attribute->getIsRequired() && '' == trim($this->getTaxvat())) {
        $errors[] = Mage::helper('customer')->__('The TAX/VAT number is required.');
    }
    $attribute = Mage::getModel('customer/attribute')->loadByCode($entityType, 'gender');
    if ($attribute->getIsRequired() && '' == trim($this->getGender())) {
        $errors[] = Mage::helper('customer')->__('Gender is required.');
    }

    if( Mage::getStoreConfig('validate_captcha/server_side_validation/enabled') ) {
        $errors = $this->validateCaptcha($errors);
    }

    if (empty($errors)) {
        return true;
    }
    return $errors;
}

private function validateCaptcha( $errors ) {

    /* additional reCAPTCHA validation */

    $action = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getActionName();
    if ( $action == 'createpost' ) {

        $captcha = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost('g-recaptcha-response', 1);
        if ( $captcha == '' ) {

            $errors[] = Mage::helper('customer')->__('Please check the reCAPTCHA field to continue.');
        } else {
            $params = array();
            $params['secret'] =  Mage::getStoreConfig('validate_captcha/server_side_validation/secret_key');
            $params['response'] = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost('g-recaptcha-response', 1);
            $params['remoteip'] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

            $params_string = http_build_query($params);
            $url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?'.$params_string;

            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
            curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            $response = curl_exec( $ch );

            $result = json_decode( $response, true );
            if ( trim( $result['success'] ) != true ) {

                // This will be shown at the top of the registration page
                $errors[] = Mage::helper('customer')->__('reCAPTCHA unable to verify.');
            }
        }
    }

    return $errors;

}}
```

Please refer my site for layout and config file.
https://www.pearlbells.co.uk/invisible-recaptcha-register-form-magento/